# How to display calendar on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am getting issue on calendar on popup. I have created popup and i want to display calendar on popup.I tried the code but calendar not displaying.Please help me. check the URL http://test.hybreed.co/sirius/ below you will get Popup option click on that than popup will display.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sirius Sport</title>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



    <style>
    #popupBoxThreePosition{
        top: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 120%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); display: none;
      }
      .popupBoxWrapper{
        width: 70%;height: 100%; margin: 50px auto; text-align: left;
      }
      .popupBoxContent{
        background-color: #FFF; padding: 15px;
      }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<!--Section2-->
<section>
    <div id="content_1" class="content">


<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="post2">

  <div class="box">


      <div id="wrapper">

      <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxThreePosition');"><h4>Popup</h4></a> </p>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    </div>
</section>
<!--End Section2-->



<!-- Popup content -->
<div id="popupBoxThreePosition">
      <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
        <div class="popupBoxContent">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">

      </div>

</div>

  <div id="datepicker"></div><!-- calender-->


          <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxThreePosition');"><h5>Close</h5></a></p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <!--End Popup-->







<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/popup.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/viewportchecker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
      classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInLeft', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
      offset: 100    
     });   
});     

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post2').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
      classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInRight', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
      offset: 100    
     });   
});     


function toggle_visibility(id) {
             var e = document.getElementById(id);
             if(e.style.display == 'block')
                e.style.display = 'none';
             else
                e.style.display = 'block';
          }



    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, remove your CSS and JS from the HTML file and into their own files. 2nd: share us an example with the smallest amount of code possible, that still replicates your problem.

Comment: You have errors in your code. Check the browser console

Comment: your link tags is not closed due to which it is causing errors

Comment: due to unclosed link tags the jquery ui is not loading

Comment: please suggest me more where i have to change the code

Comment: hi Amit i closed the tag also but still getting issue

Comment: Also you are including both jquery-ui 11.2 and 11.4 You should remove one of them

Comment: Changes are done but nothing is happing.

Comment: put this in bottom <script> $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); </script>

Comment: see my code below in the answer @Hybreeder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code think it can help..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sport</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />


    <style>
    #popupBoxThreePosition{
        top: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 120%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); display: none;
      }
      .popupBoxWrapper{
        width: 70%;height: 100%; margin: 50px auto; text-align: left;
      }
      .popupBoxContent{
        background-color: #FFF; padding: 15px;
      }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<!--Section2-->
<section>
    <div id="content_1" class="content">

  <h2> Sport</h2>
      <p>Subheading Subheading Subheading</p>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="post">
  <div class="box " >

      <img src="Images/section1.jpg" alt="" style="height:300px;width:400px; ">
      <h4>Learn to sail Camps & Events at H20</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>

<div id="wrapper">

      <p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxThreePosition');">
          <h4>Popup</h4>
        </a> 
      </p>

    </div>

    </div>  </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="post2">

  <div class="box">
      <img src="Images/section2.jpg" alt="" style="height:300px;width:400px;">
      <h4> My First Sailing Experience</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>

      <div id="wrapper">

      <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxThreePosition');"><h4>Popup</h4></a> </p>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    </div>
</section>
<!--End Section2-->



<!-- Popup content -->
<div id="popupBoxThreePosition">
      <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
        <div class="popupBoxContent">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                  <h3>MURUD JANJIRA</h3>
                 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text </p>
                </div>

            </div>

           <input class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" />


            <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxThreePosition');"><h5>Close</h5></a></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!--End Popup-->







<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/popup.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/viewportchecker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
})

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
      classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInLeft', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
      offset: 100    
     });   
});     

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post2').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
      classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInRight', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
      offset: 100    
     });   
});     


function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You are loading jquery first so it is not getting the right jquery ..
I hope this solution will fix your problem..

Comment: Hi amit i am really appreciate your code but i don't want to use text.I want to display directly calendar if any one click on popup

Comment: than change input to div you will get the calender when user click on popup

Comment: use this `<div class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" />` instead of `<input class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" />`

Comment: Yes,now my issue is resolved .Thanks for your help Mr.Amit.I am really appreciate your code once again thanks

Comment: Amit, Is there any option to change the position of calendar on popup?

Comment: you have to style div

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues:?

You have too many same scripts in a single page:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
```

Here you have **2** versions of **jquery ui** library. and below at the bottom you have some other scripts and library referenced.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/viewportchecker.js"></script>
```

Here at the bottom you have another reference of jQuery lib.

```
<script>
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

And you have a datepicker code which should be wrapped in `doc ready` which ensures that the DOM *(Document Object Model)* is ready and you can use it to manipulate.

If you don't wrap it within doc ready block then it will execute as soon as browser renders this script line by line.

So if tell you what would be the issue then i would say that when you run your datepicker code at that point of time the dom element `<div id="datepicker"></div><!-- calender-->` wasn't ready/loaded in the page.

That is the reason we should always either wrap the code in `.ready()/DOMContentLoaded` event block
or
we can put all the scripts below at the bottom of the page which also ensures that all the dom nodes are available for the javascript.

So there might be some conflict issues with different versions of same libraries.

#### Solution:

Well you can use different versions of jQuery in a single page but its better to utilize one which is available so i would use these:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script><!-- This should be included before jquery ui-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script><!-- This should always be included after jquery lib but before ui widget script usage-->
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/viewportchecker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ // doc ready block.
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); // <----datepicker code initializer here
        jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
             classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInLeft', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
              offset: 100    
         });   

         jQuery('.post2').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
             classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInRight', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
             offset: 100    
         });   
    });     


     function toggle_visibility(id) {
         var e = document.getElementById(id);
         if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
         else
            e.style.display = 'block';
      }
</script>
```